# My values keep defaulting to Date.now() for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I'm trying to set a start and end date in a state in React. Whenever I try to set it with values of my own Javascript decides to change the whole format and values(as if I'm using DateNow)

[Console log of what's Happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0ZJv.png)

I genuinely don't know what's happening.

This is the code that manages the state it's on a `useEffect` so that it updates once the product information reaches the Front server.

```js
if (CoutureRentalState.reservasDelProducto != initialCoutureRental.reservasDelProducto) {
  invalid = []
  CoutureRentalState.reservasDelProducto.forEach(reserva => {
    invalid.push({
      start: `${reserva.inicioReserva[0]}-${reserva.inicioReserva[1]}-${reserva.inicioReserva[2]}`,
      end: `${reserva.finReserva[0]}-${reserva.finReserva[1]}-${reserva.finReserva[2]}`
    })
  });
  console.log("Invalidas");
  console.log(invalid);
  setFechasInvalidas(invalid)
  console.log("State");
  console.log(fechasInvalidas);
}
```

I thought this was going to just take an object with the year, month and day turn it into a string, and pass it down to the state. But everything just runs a few times and then the values are all messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by directly creating a new Date(object). This directly creates a date with the values I want. However, it doesn´t fix the problem of using just a string instead of a date.

```
      if (CoutureRentalState.reservasDelProducto != initialCoutureRental.reservasDelProducto) {
    invalid = []
    setFechasInvalidas(invalid)
    CoutureRentalState.reservasDelProducto.forEach(reserva => {
      invalid.push({
        start: new Date(reserva.inicioReserva),
        end: new Date(reserva.finReserva)
      })
      setFechasInvalidas(invalid)
    });
  }
```